# Is there a place to test if code is ES5 compliant / safe?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Sometimes I'd like to know if the code I'm writing is ES5 compliant/safe or not.

**Example:** this would fail because of the arrow function.

```
() => "something";
```

I know `Babel` could take care of this. But sometimes I would like to test some cases.

Is there a place where I could do this?

Comment: internet explorer?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=es6 or you can try modernizr - it have tools to launch polyfills in case something does not work.

Comment: Simply run your code in Internet Explorer 11. Beware that IE 11 supports `const` and `let`.

Comment: @Zydnar I use "caniuse.com" a lot. But sometimes I don't find what I need. Thanks

Comment: This is good question. There must be in chrome ...

Answer (score 10):

Try ESlint, https://eslint.org/demo. You can disable advanced rules and stick to the basics.

For example, with an arrow function on ES5: https://eslint.org/demo#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiKCkgPT4gXCJzb21ldGhpbmdcIjsiLCJvcHRpb25zIjp7InBhcnNlck9wdGlvbnMiOnsiZWNtYVZlcnNpb24iOjUsInNvdXJjZVR5cGUiOiJzY3JpcHQiLCJlY21hRmVhdHVyZXMiOnt9fSwicnVsZXMiOnt9LCJlbnYiOnt9fX0=

It could also be automated as part of a build/ci script.

Comment: This partially worked. It works well for syntax. But the code `someString.someUndefinedMethod(whatever)` does not show any errors. It's not aware of ES5 prototype methods. [Link](https://eslint.org/demo#eyJ0ZXh0IjoidmFyIHggPSBcInNvbWVTdHJpbmdcIjtcblxueC5zb21lVW5kZWZpbmVkTWV0aG9kKFwiYWFhYVwiKTsiLCJvcHRpb25zIjp7InBhcnNlck9wdGlvbnMiOnsiZWNtYVZlcnNpb24iOjUsInNvdXJjZVR5cGUiOiJzY3JpcHQiLCJlY21hRmVhdHVyZXMiOnt9fSwicnVsZXMiOnt9LCJlbnYiOnt9fX0=)

Comment: @cbdeveloper due to the nature of JS, methods are not type-checked. As far as I know, there is no rule for that in ESLint. Unless you are using a type-checking compiler like [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUwhAhgcwQLhtATgSzDRgF4YByACwQBsaQYB3EXGgE3IG4AoRZdBADoIIRAFUwbBADNCCNgFkEUSiDYAKAJTdQkEDSH006vqgybOQA), there is no way to know if `someUndefinedMethod` was not defined by a third party library for example.

Comment: You are right! I think I need an ES5 environment to actually (try to) run some code . Thanks